# In Timber pass an ID in the loop to a WP function

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

In Timber/Twig I am displaying a list of events using:

page-events.php:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();

$events = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$context['events'] = Timber::get_posts( $events );

Timber::render( array( 'page-' . $post->post_name . '.twig', 'page-home.twig' ), $context );
```

page-events.twig

```
{% for event in events %}
    <li>{{ event.name }} - *country* </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

I would also like to show the country associated with the event. This is stored as a term. In WordPress, I would normally retrieve this using:

```
$country = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'country');
echo $country[0]->name;
```

How would I pass the ID to `get_the_terms($id, 'country')` using Timber?

I have searched the Timber documentation and Googled but cannot find an answer.

I have tried `{{ get_the_term( event.id, 'country' ) }}` and `{% get_the_term( event.id, 'country' ) %}` and similar, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a PHP function in Twig, you need to use `function()` or `fn()`, as explained in the [Functions Guide](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/).

For you this would mean that in Twig, instead of `{{ get_the_term( event.id, 'country' ) }}`, you could use

```
{{ fn( 'get_the_terms', event.id, 'country' ) }}
```

You were on the right track to pass the ID via `event.id`. However, that function returns an array, which you can’t display like this. You need to convert it to a string or loop over it. Here’s how you could display only the first country in that array using Twig’s [first](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/first.html) filter:

```
{{ fn( 'get_the_terms', event.id, 'country' )|first }}
```

If you’d have multiple countries, you could turn them into a comma-separated list with [join](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html):

```
{{ fn( 'get_the_terms', event.id, 'country' )|join(', ') }}
```

There’s one more thing that we can optimize. Instead of using `get_the_terms()`, we can make use of the [`terms()`](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#terms) method that is available for `Timber\Post` objects:

```
{% for event in events %}
    <li>{{ event.name }} - {{ event.terms('country')|first }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```